# display images from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display images from the database.
In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Display(int id, Document doc)
{
    byte[] byteArray = doc.Content;//its has the image in bytes
    return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray), "image/jpeg");
}
```

In View:

```
@foreach (var imgsrc in Model.ImagesSrc)
{ 
     <img src="@Url.Action( "Display", "image", new { id = @imgsrc.Id } )" alt="" />
}
```

It is not working

Comment: "It is not working" is not a good enough description of what's happening. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: In output it showing an image with question mark

Comment: So have you tried to download the file that's being served? Looked at the network traffic with Wireshark? What sort of diagnostics have you tried?

Comment: in the view source, image tag has the following format <img src="/image/Display/26321" alt=""> whether it is correct or not

Comment: Well it's certainly *unusual* for an image URL not to include an extension, but what happens if you try to fetch that URL? Does it download anything? Basically you need to do some diagnosis work yourself...

Comment: I am new to mvc. i don't know how to explain it. Can u send an example for it.

Comment: You don't need to know about MVC to do the diagnostics - if you fetch that URL directly, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is expecting a `Document doc` but your url is only defining the id. You should fetch the document inside the download method with the id

```
public ActionResult Display(int id)
{
    Document doc = GetDocById(id);
    byte[] byteArray = doc.Content;//its has the image in bytes
    return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray), "image/jpeg");
}
```